# Linq Select with group by to avoid repetition

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, group-by

I'm developing an Entity Framework 4.4.0.0 Code First library with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

I have this data on `Messages` table:

[image]

As you can see, there are repeated messages.

And I have this LinQ to retrieve that messages:

```
var msgs = from message in context.Messages
            where message.TalkId == talkId &&
                (message.SentBy == userId || message.SentTo == userId)
            orderby message.DateUtcSent
            select message;
```

But I get most of them.

**How can I do to get that messages without repetition?**

If I'm user with userId == 15, I want to get messages with `MessageId`: 32, 36, 39 and 42.

**Do you know how can I do it with LinQ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by in order to group your result by user for example.

Here's a link that should help you: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea